# mac usb flash drive unrecognized in disk utility, only shown in system report

Tags: mac, usb, usb-flash-drive, boot-camp

After trying to install bootcamp I had an error. After this my USB drive is no longer recognized. It still appears in system report. If I connect it to Windows it tells me that the device is not recognized.

I tried a lot of things:

- reset smc
- reset nvram
- lists with disk utils

How can I repair the usb drive?

[image: c]

Comment: If Windows also sees an error, I'd wager the USB itself is defective - does it work on another computer?

Comment: was working fine, it only stopped working when bootcamp had a problem and all the partitions disappeared

Answer (score 0):

remove your USB and try this in terminal:
  `diskutil list` 
now note the list, insert your USB and run another command : `ls -al /dev/ | grep disk` 
 a new disk name is added. something  like "disk1s1". it is your flash drive. 

 now you just need to mount it in terminal by it's name. here my device is disk1a1: 
 `diskutil mount -mountPoint /Volumes/ /dev/disk1s1`

Comment: I tried to do this but it didn't work:

> ls -al /dev/ | grep disk
brw-r-----   1 root               operator         1,   0 Mar 23 19:50 disk0
brw-r-----   1 root               operator         1,   1 Mar 23 19:50 disk0s1
brw-r-----   1 root               operator         1,   2 Mar 23 19:50 disk0s2
brw-r-----   1 root               operator         1,   3 Mar 23 19:50 disk1
brw-r-----   1 root               operator         1,   4 Mar 23 19:50 disk1s1
brw-r-----   1 root               operator         1,   5 Mar 23 19:50 disk1s2

Comment: send the result of first command too, pls

Comment: thanks https://gist.github.com/cristyansv/131cb4ea8d76487ebe68d31e4137515e

Comment: ok, open your Disk Utility on mac , if you can see your Device select it and click on first aid. if it didn't work, your USB is damaged.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to re-format the USB drive?  You will lose any data on the drive but it may repair it.  If you have important files on the USB drive, then ignore this answer ;)

If using Windows to perform the format I recommend UNCHECKING the box that says "Quick Format" (other OS's may have a similar option).  This takes longer but will make Windows perform a more thorough format.